# Visual Studio 2019 refusing to build solution C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

For some reason, Visual studio has suddenly refused to build my c++ files. Also, when it pops up with "there were build errors, would you like to continue with the last successful build" and I press yes it then says unable to start program. I am running Windows 10 with the latest updates and Visual Studio 2019 also with the latest updates.

What happens when it says unable to start program:

[image]

This is what my build output shows:
EDIT: Here is the new version after I removed all copies of variables and combed through all of the previous errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MasterApp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MasterApp.cpp

1>C:\Users\foo\source\repos\MasterApp\MasterApp.cpp(33,15): warning C4244: 
'argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

1>masterappRef.cpp

1>Generating Code...

1>masterappRef.obj : error LNK2005: "double version" (?version@@3NA) already 
defined in MasterApp.obj

1>C:\Users\foo\source\repos\MasterApp\Debug\MasterApp.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

1>Done building project "MasterApp.vcxproj" -- FAILED

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Code Below:

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
// MasterApp.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.


#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "MasterAppRef.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

//global variables
string passwd_admin = "admin";
string PassEntered;
string Username1 = "admin";
string Username2 = "administrator";
string UserEntered;
double version = 2.4;







int main()
{

    //setting console window title
    SetConsoleTitle ( TEXT("Master App"));
    //seed for the randomiser
    srand(time(NULL));

    //declaring variable
    int randomDice;
    system("cls");

    cout << "Please login\n";
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Enter Username: ";
    cin >> UserEntered;
    if (UserEntered == Username1) {

    }
    else if (UserEntered == Username2) {

    }
    else if (UserEntered != Username2 && UserEntered != Username1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

    system("cls");
    cout << "Please login\n\n";
    cout << "Enter Password: ";
    cin >> PassEntered;

    if (PassEntered == passwd_admin) {
        cout << "\nAccess Granted!\n\n\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong Password";
        return 0;

    }
    system("cls");

    cout << "\n\n                                                     [  Starting  ]\n";
    cout << "                                                Press enter to continue";

    system("pause >nul");
    system("cls");
    Sleep(2200);

    cout << "\n\n\nMaster App " << version << " 2020\n\n";
    Sleep(1530);

    bool played = PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\foo\\startup.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
    Sleep(3000);
    int choice;
    system("cls");


    cout << "\nMaster App                                                           Version " << version << "\n\n";

    cout << "Choose and option and then press enter\n";
    cout << "(E.g. 1 [PRESS ENTER] will give you choice number 1)\n\n";

    cout << "1) Close App\n";
    cout << "2) Roll the Dice\n";
    cout << "3) Pull up some ASCII art\n";
    cout << "4) Give me a random number\n";
    cout << "5) Give me some insparation\n";
    cout << "6) Open Administrator Panel\n";
    cout << "7) Play music\n";
    cout << "8) Open Command Prompt\n";
    cout << "9) See Change Log\n";
    cout << "10) Open Calculator\n";
    cout << "11) Open New Notepad\n";
    cout << "12) Clock\n";
    cout << "13) Ask the magical 8 ball\n";

    cout << "\n\nYour choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {

        randomDice = rand() % 6 + 1;
        cout << "\n "<<"And your dice has rolled... " << randomDice <<"!\n";
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (choice == 3) {
        //This is the only ascii art that doesn't have backslashes.
        cout << " _______  _______  _______  ___   ___     _______  ______    _______  __  \n";
        cout << "|   _   ||       ||       ||   | |   |   |   _   ||    _ |  |       ||  |\n";
        cout << "|  |_|  ||  _____||       ||   | |   |   |  |_|  ||   | ||  |_     _||  | \n";
        cout << "|       || |_____ |       ||   | |   |   |       ||   |_||_   |   |  |  |\n";
        cout << "|       ||_____  ||      _||   | |   |   |       ||    __  |  |   |  |__| \n";
        cout << "|   _   | _____| ||     |_ |   | |   |   |   _   ||   |  | |  |   |   __ \n";
        cout << "|__| |__||_______||_______||___| |___|   |__| |__||___|  |_|  |___|  |__| \n";
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (choice == 4) {
        int randomNumber;

        randomNumber = rand() % 10000 + 1;
        cout << "\n " << "Your random number is: " << randomNumber << "\n";
        system("pause");

    }
    else if (choice == 5) {
        int inspNum;
        inspNum = rand() % 6 + 1;
        if (inspNum == 6) {
            cout << "Life is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance, you must keep moving.\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        else if (inspNum == 5) {
            cout << "Those who think they are dumb are actually the smart ones...\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        else if (inspNum == 4) {
            cout << "Act like what you're doing matters - It does.\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        else if (inspNum == 3) {
            //By Albert Einstein
            cout << "Success is not final, failure is not fatal: it is the courage to continue that counts.\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        else if (inspNum == 2) {
            cout << "Never bend your head. Always hold it high. Look the world straight in the eye.\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        else if (inspNum == 1) {
            cout << "What you get by achieving your goals is not as important as what you become by achieving your goals.\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error!\n";
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }else if (choice == 6) {

        system("cls");
        string adminName = "Administrator";
        string adminPass = "administrator";
        string iu;
        string ip;




        cout << "Enter Administrator Username: ";
        cin >> iu;
        if (iu == adminName) {
            cout << "Enter Password: ";
            cin >> ip;
            if (ip == adminPass) {
                cout << "Access Granted! You may proceed now.\n\n";
                system("pause");
            }
            else {
                cout << "Incorrect Password!\n";
                system("pause");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Incorect Username!\n";
                system("pause");
                return 0;
        }
        system("cls");
        cout << "Administrator Panel\n\n";


        int adminChoice;


        cout << "Options:\n";
        cout << "1) See Change Log\n";
        cout << "2) Close App\n";
        cout << "3) Change Colour\n";
        cin >> adminChoice;


        if (adminChoice == 1) {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Change Log\n\n";

            cout << "Version " << version << "\n\n";

            cout << "1) More options\n";
            cout << "2) Added more music and credited music artists/websites\n";
            cout << "3) Administrator panel discontinued - slowly migrating to main panel\n";
            cout << "4) Added something new...\n";



        }
        else if (adminChoice == 2) {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Closing...";
            Sleep(3000);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (adminChoice == 3) {
            cout << "Switch Colour to...\n\n";

            cout << "1) Default\n";
            cout << "2) High Contrast\n";
            int colourChoice = 1;
            cin >> colourChoice;
            if (colourChoice == 1) {
                system("color");
                system("cls");
                system("pause");
            }
            else if (colourChoice == 2) {
                system("color fc");
                system("pause <nul");

            }
        }


    }

    else if (choice == 7) {
    system("cls");

    cout << "Choose a song to play:\n\n";

    cout << "Sample Music\n\n";

    cout << "1) Beethoven's 9th Symphony (11:48)\n";
    cout << "2) Beethoven's 1st Symphony (26:12)\n";
    cout << "\nUpbeat Music\n\n";

    cout << "3) Piano Piece (2:02)\n";
    cout << "\nMore coming soon!\n";
    int song;
    cin >> song;
    if (song == 1) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\nPLaying: Beethoven's 9th Symphony\n\n";
        PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\foo\\beethoven.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
        cout << "\n\n\nPress any key to stop playing\n";
        system("pause >nul");
    }
    else if (song == 2) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\nPlaying: Beethoven's 1st Symphony\n\n";
        PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\foo\\beethoven1.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
        cout << "\n\n\nPress any key to stop playing\n";
        system("pause >nul");
    }
    else if (song == 3) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\nPlaying: Upbeat Piano Piece\n\n";
        PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\foo\\upbeatpiano.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
        cout << "\n\n\nPress any key to stop playing\n";
        system("pause >nul");
    }


    }
    else if (choice == 8) {
    system("cmd.exe");
    system("cd C:\\Windows\\System32");
    system("pause >nul");
    }
    else if (choice == 9) {
    void versionInfo();
    }
    else if (choice == 10) {
    system("cls");
    system("calc.exe");
    cout << "Opening Calculator...\n";
    system("pause >nul");
    }
    else if (choice == 11) {
    system("notepad");
    }
    else if (choice == 12) {
    system("cls");
    system("date /t");
    cout << "\n";
    system("time /t");
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    }
    else if (choice == 13) {
    system("cls");
    int eightBall;
    eightBall = rand() % 6 + 1;
    cout << "Ask the magical eight-ball a question! Press enter when you have it...";
    system("pause >nul");
    system("cls");
    if (eightBall == 1) {
        cout << "Think harder and try again...\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (eightBall == 2) {
        cout << "Seems like a good idea\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (eightBall == 3) {
        cout << "No, don't.\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (eightBall == 4) {
        cout << "YAAAAASSS!\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (eightBall == 5) {
        cout << "Hmm... I didn't get that. Try again.\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (eightBall == 6) {
        cout << "Um, sure\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (eightBall == 7) {
        cout << "It's up to you, but I would say no.\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();

    }
    else if (eightBall == 8) {
        cout << "Well, I would think that you shouldn't\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    }
    else if (choice == 14) {

    system("cls");


    }




}
```

MasterAppRef.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;






int main();
//declaring functions
void versionInfo();
void eightBallFunction();
```

MasterAppRef.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "MasterAppRef.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
double version;


}
void eightBallFunction() {
    system("cls");
    int TryeightBall;
    TryeightBall = rand() % 6 + 1;
    cout << "Ask the magical eight-ball a question! Press enter when you have it...";
    system("pause >nul");
    system("cls");
    if (TryeightBall == 1) {
        cout << "Think harder and try again...\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (TryeightBall == 2) {
        cout << "Seems like a good idea\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (TryeightBall == 3) {
        cout << "No, don't.\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (TryeightBall == 4) {
        cout << "YAAAAASSS!\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (TryeightBall == 5) {
        cout << "Hmm... I didn't get that. Try again.\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (TryeightBall == 6) {
        cout << "Um, sure\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();
    }
    else if (TryeightBall == 7) {
        cout << "It's up to you, but I would say no.\n";
        system("pause");
        void eightBallFunction();

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does global variables in a header file cause link error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593048/why-does-global-variables-in-a-header-file-cause-link-error)

Comment: Please show a [mre] and post the compiler errors as text not screenshots. You have more than one copy of `version` defined

Comment: So the problem is the variable `version`. That's obvious from the build error. So why not post the code you have concering the variable `version`. Didn't you think that was relevant?

Comment: You defined the variable `version` twice.

Comment: @ChrisMM I have pasted my code in and I can't see where I have defined version twice. Could you please point it out to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first block of code you provided, you have

```
double version = 2.4;
```

The in MasterAppRef.cpp, you have

```
double version;
```

Therefore, you have two definitions of `version`. If these are supposed to refer to the same variable, then in a single header file you would put:

```
extern double version;
```

Then both .cpp files would include that header file. Only one of the .cpp files would then have the definition (your first block, for example). If they are supposed to refer to different variables, then you have two options. One, rename them to have unique names. Or two, put them inside anonymous namespaces. i.e.

```
namespace {
    double version;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is not problem in code, your program may running after you closed it, so VS just can`t get access to your program file, search your program using cmd command tasklist, if it is there, kill it using taskkill, or just reload your pc.

Comment: this is linking issue, not that the exe is running. There are multiple `version` variables in the code

Comment: @phuclv I have seen that, but I have removed all but one of the version variables and tried again, but VS gives off the same error.

Comment: @Jim the issue is probably because you put it in a header file, so each compilation unit (i.e. cpp file) has its own instance of `version`. No one can tell until you post your code here

Comment: @phuclv I have now added the code into the question.